# How to detect a user's log out from Facebook?

Tags: facebook, google-app-engine, facebook-graph-api

I am using Google App Engine and deploying my app on Facebook as a Facebook canvas app (the app gets loaded in the iframe and so on)

I redirect the player to the Facebook log in page when he visits the homepage with an empty session. Then I fill the session once the player logs in using the graph API.

The problem now is that when a player signs out of Facebook, my sessions keeps the records stored and the user stays signed into the app.

I want to detect if the user logs out of Facebook, preferably from the server side.

Answer (score 0):

Try to subscribe to the logout event:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function (){
    // do stuff
});
```

Or try this:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
    alert('The status of the session is: ' + response.status);
});
```

Look here:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to detect on your server if the user has logged out of Facebook.  When you call into the graph API using their user access token Facebook will respond with this (if they've logged out of facebook)

```
{
  "error": {
    "type":"OAuthException","message":"Error validating 
      access token: The session is invalid because the 
      user logged out."
   }
}
```